# Create LinkedIn user using Graph API

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Is it possible to create LinkedIn user in Azure AD B2C using Graph API?

I can see that when I create LinkedIn user using hosted pages, the following user is created in directory

[image: LinkedIn user created by hosted page]

But when I query users endpoint, I don't see any properties on the user object that would say, that he is a LinkedIn user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a LinkedIn user. It is a user who created an account in your Azure AD B2C using LinkedIn as an identity provider.

For you, as the Azure AD B2C administrator, it does not matter where the user has authenticated. You can not create a user account with a fixed identity provider.

Comment: Ok, this is what I was afraid of. Thank you.

Comment: I guess the only way to go is to create a normal user using Graph API and store his LinkedIn Id in an extension property on User object. Then a custom sign in policy using Identity Experience Framework has to be created to match Id from LinkedIn token against this extension property. I have done this and it works.

Comment: I do not see the point in what you are doing. Can you describe more generally what is your main problem to solve?

Comment: I want to sign up LinkedIn users on my own website, not on those pages hosted by Azure. I will authenticate LinkedIn users using OpenId and gather their profile data and then keep this data in Azure AD directory. Then I want to be able to sign in as this user using Azure AD B2C sign in page.

Comment: Nope. You don't want to sign up LinkedIn users. What you really want is to sign up a user (create a user account in Azure AD B2C, not 'on your website') with LinkedIn as an identity provider. Do you feel the difference? You don't need any extension properties to achieve this.

Comment: But the point is that I have to get user data on my website and keep it in Azure AD. And then I have to allow him to sign in to my website using LinkedIn using login.microsoft.com and get his data from AD. Those are the requirements of my system. I have to match somehow his LinkedIn profile to the data I store in Azure AD. Can you explain how can this be achieved without extension properties and custom policy?

Comment: What data you store in Azure AD? Can you give an example?